# Form transparency from static void C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012

Basically, I have a timer that once reaches 5000ms will set the opacity of my main form to 0.5
The problem is that I can't change the opacity of my form from a static void...
Here is my code, any sugestions? :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
        // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.
        myTimer.Interval = 5000;
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    public static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                        EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
        //Set Opacity here

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your static method doesn't have an instance of the form to work with.

The simplest approach is just to stop it from being a static method. There's no obvious reason why you'd want it to be a static method anyway - or why you'd want `myTimer` to be static, which I assume it is, based on the usage.

Once you've made it an instance method, you can just change the opacity as you normally would, assuming that the `Timer` in question is a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (so it'll be ticking on the right thread...)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am feeling really stupid right now...
Problem solved :)